# generic createview and django form only rendering a button in a template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-generic-views

I have encountered a funny challenge, as am building some apps where they want track some expenses and revenues profits ...
I used generic views to create and get details and delete, all work fine with expenses, but I copied the same code and I used it for revenues from expenses you can't imagine this view is rendering a button only yet it has a form, NOTE SAME CODE WORK WELL ON EXPENSES. I even exchanged templates but it kept rendering the former content even after changing the template. it doesn't matter what's in the template the view just renders the same thing even when I remove the form, even when I put pass.

```
class AccountsRevenueCreate(CreateView):
template_name='dashboard/expense_create.html'
model= AccountsExpense
success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard:expenses')
form_class=AccountsExpenseForm
```

and the form

```
class AccountsRevenueForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = AccountsRevenue
    fields = '__all__'
```

and in the template

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                       <h5 class="form-title"><span>revenue Update 
                     </span></h5>
                    </div>
                    <form method="post", action="{% url 
                    'dashboard:revenue_add' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                       
                     {% comment %} {{ form|crispy }} {% endcomment %}     
                     {{ form.as_p }} 

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-12 col-sm-12">Save 
                    </button>
                   </form>
                 </div>
```

and the URLs

```
path ('accounts/revenues/create/', AccountsRevenueCreate.as_view(), name='revenue_create'),
```

I have chosen to show you only where the problem is not paste unnecessary code

here are the models you requested me to update

```
from django.db import models

class AccountsRevenue(models.Model):
revenue_of = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='',null=False)
revenue_by = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='',null=False)
amount = models.IntegerField( default='100,000') 
day_on_which = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
evidence_document = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'uploads/', blank=True, default='')
signature = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'uploads/', blank=True, default='')


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.revenue_of)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('dashboard:revenue', kwargs= {'pk':self.pk} )

def get_document(self):
    if self.evidence_document and hasattr(self.evidence_document, 'url'):
        return self.evidence_document.url
    else:
        return "/static/assets/img/user.png"




 class AccountsExpense(models.Model):
expense_of= models.CharField(max_length=250, default='',null=False)
expense_by = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='',null=False)
amount = models.IntegerField( default='100,000') 
day_on_which = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
evidence_document = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'uploads/', 
blank=True, default='')
signature = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'uploads/', blank=True, 
 default='')


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.expense_of)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('dashboard:expense', kwargs= {'pk':self.pk} )

def get_document(self):
    if self.evidence_document and hasattr(self.evidence_document, 
    'url'):
        return self.evidence_document.url
    else:
        return "/static/assets/img/user.png"







from django.urls import URLPattern, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from. views import profiles, Profile_detail, Profile_update, 
Profile_delete, dashboard, Profile_create,\
AccountsRevenues, revenue_detail_view, AccountsRevenueUpdate, 
AccountsRevenue_delete, \
AccountsExpenses, AccountsExpenseDetail, AccountsExpenseCreate, 
AccountsExpenseUpdate, AccountsExpenseDelete,\
        userprofileupdate, revenue_add, AccountsRevenueCreate
         


app_name = "dashboard"
urlpatterns = [

path ('accounts/revenues', AccountsRevenues.as_view(), name='revenues'),
path ('accounts/revenues/<str:pk>/', revenue_detail_view, 
name='revenue'),
path ('accounts/revenues/<str:pk>/update/', 
AccountsRevenueUpdate.as_view(), name='revenue_update'),
path ('accounts/revenues/<str:pk>/delete/', 
AccountsRevenue_delete.as_view(), name='revenue_delete'),
path ('accounts/revenues/create/', AccountsRevenueCreate.as_view(), 
name='revenue_create'),


# accounts expenses 
path ('accounts/expenses', AccountsExpenses.as_view(), name='expenses'),
path ('accounts/expenses/<str:pk>', AccountsExpenseDetail.as_view(), 
name='expense'),
path ('accounts/expenses/<str:pk>/update/', 
AccountsExpenseUpdate.as_view(), name='expense_update'),
path ('accounts/expenses/<str:pk>/delete/', 
 AccountsExpenseDelete.as_view(), name='expense_delete'),
path ('accounts/expenses/create/', AccountsExpenseCreate.as_view(), 
name='expense_create'),
```

]

I have added a screenshot of what it comes out as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAZda.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the `AccountsRevenue` model? There's also a `,` in the form tag which is not needed.

Comment: Share entire code, including both the models, forms, urls and template for that, including the above imports.

Comment: @St JC try removing the line from AccountsRevenueCreate: model= AccountsExpense (you already declared the model associated with the form in the form class). If it doesn't help, show me your models.

Comment: @SunderamDubey, and inquirer I have updated all the things you suggested

Comment: @StJC did you see my answer to you?

Answer (score 1):

left model.py, forms.py, urls.py as it was.

views.py
in the line: template_name = 'bboard/expense_create.html' replace bboard with the name of the folder where the templates are located. I have it templates/bboard. Also in your field: **form_class=AccountsExpenseForm changed to form_class = AccountsRevenueForm.**
And the return goes to the same page with the form: success_url = reverse_lazy('revenue_create').

success_url can then be returned to what it was, now you need to make sure that everything works.

views.py

```
class AccountsRevenueCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/expense_create.html'
    model = AccountsExpense
    success_url = reverse_lazy('revenue_create')
    form_class = AccountsRevenueForm
```

expense_create.html
**in the template you have an error form method="post", there should not be a comma.**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h5 class="form-title"><span>revenue Update
                     </span></h5>
    </div>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'revenue_create' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% comment %} {{ form|crispy }} {% endcomment %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-12 col-sm-12">Save
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Followed the link: http://localhost:8000/accounts/revenues/create/

Screenshot attached:
[image]

Comment: Oh so kind of you Mr @inquirer I am a little bit ashamed here because it's not working, I tried to divide the views into different folders to see if that would work with your suggested solutions but then another more dangerous error fell in. ```ValueError at /dashboard/accounts/revenues/create/
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create'.``` this one I have tried to research as some suggest you have to delete the migrations which I did and I even dumped the whole database, and the error persisted. And do you know what? The first project is deployed and i can do more since now I have errors

Comment: @StJC didn't get any errors, though I didn't fill in both ImageField fields. The data was successfully saved to the database.

Comment: Sir/Madam @inquirer the error you see above in my latest comment before this, help me fix it because it because I have literally failed, I even changed the views to function based, same error. And I am wondering why it's happening with revenues not expenses yet they similar 100% 

Comment: Dear Sir/Madam St JC, would you like to be referred to like this.? I'm a man. My modest knowledge is not enough to understand the depth of your thoughts. In the form I used classes like Accounts Revenue and Accounts Expense. 

If you have made a view function, you can use request to receiving data and see what the form returns.

Comment: hey everyone including @inquirer the last problem was solved by a solution here https://splunktool.com/django-valueerror-field-id-expected-a-number-but-got-s, the extreme last answer, which was extending the URL with an additional string, Thanks. We get better even as we get challenged