# django 404 error The current path, didn’t match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have such error, when I try edit or delete:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/
Using the URLconf defined in lab4new.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

create/
edit/<int:id>/
delete/<int:id>/
The current path, edit/, didn’t match any of these.
```

but I can't get what's wrong with path:

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from lab4 import views
 
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index),
    path("create/", views.create),
    path("edit/<int:id>/", views.edit),
    path("delete/<int:id>/", views.delete),
]
```

**Create** works fine by the way, but what's the problem with **edit** and **delete**?

Comment: You need to have the pk in the ID/Pk in the url, that's what the `<int:id>` means. ex: http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/1/

Comment: What problem are you exactly facing other than my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74059524/17562044) answer, can you share the view also?

Answer (score 2):

As @Nealium stated in [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74058115/django-404-error-the-current-path-didn-t-match-any-of-these#comment130761419_74058115) comment, you should also give some id as  you mentioned `<int:id>` in URL params for both the views.

So the requested URL should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/1` (for edit view) and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete/1` (for delete view).

Comment: it doesn't work for him, nor does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74049672/invalid-block-tag-on-line-4-endblock-did-you-forget-to-register-or-load-this#comment130758778_74049672) question and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980591/generic-createview-and-django-form-only-rendering-a-button-in-a-template/74005212#comment130751336_74005212) one, which all work for me but don't work for those asking. I'll leave my answer for now, then I'll delete it back.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/1/
```

In your case 1 is `<int:id>`. You forgot to pass a parameter to the url. Examples and description [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/)

in the view it looks something like this:

```
def edit(request, id):
    print(id)

    return HttpResponse(f"""
        <p>Host: {12345}</p>""")
```

Comment: i try put this link, but "Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field."

Comment: @Y_sgard show views.

Comment: @Y_sgard  added code how view should look like.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/X8qR88

Comment: I sent a link to views, but I still can't figure out where I went wrong

Comment: first remove all database calls and use my code to check .

Comment: i tried it, same error.

Comment: today is troll day?

Comment: sorry, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I could upload the project folder to Google drive. Could you see what's wrong there, please?

Comment: No, I will not click on the links. Show urls.py of the project.

Comment: urls.py of the project I posted in the question

Comment: @Y_sgard Can you share full traceback of error? Also share your `Horse` model.